# dialog --menu outputs integer instead string on bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, dialog

I created a dynamic menu in bash that get it's items from a array, but when the user select a specific item, the menu displays the return code (0 or 1)

```
repositorios=() ; i=0
while read -r line; do
    let i=$i+1
repositorios+=($i "$line")
done < <( find ~ -type d -name .git )

gerenciar_repositorios=$(dialog --stdout --extra-button --help-button \
--ok-label "Acessar repositório" \
--extra-label 'Criar repositório' \
--cancel-label 'Remover repositório' \
--help-label 'Cancelar' \
--backtitle "Bem vindo ao Git Bash `whoami`!" \
--title ' Gerenciar repositórios ' \
--menu 'Gerenciar repositórios' 0 0 0 \
${repositorios[@]}) ; echo $gerenciar_repositorios
```

> **The `; echo $gerenciar_repositorios` is for testing purposes only!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your assignment

```
repositorios+=($i "$line")
```

the integer becomes the first value in each row.  That is the *tag* referred to in the manual description of **`--menu`**, which is printed on exit.  If you want to use the second part, you could do

```
repositorios+=("$line" "$line")
```

and use the **`--no-tags`** option to display a single column.  The **`no-items`** option would give a similar result in this case.